# Ошибка при установке значения атрибута при переходе MS Server 2003 -> 2008

Tags: mysql, 1с, odbc, oledb

Установка соединения:

```
DRIVER = MYSQL ODBC 5.1 Driver; SERVER = localhost; DataBase = *****; UID = user; PWD = ****
```

Всё работало и подключалось, когда использовался MS Server 2003. После переноса на MS Server 2008 стала выдаваться следующая ошибка:

> {ОбщийМодуль.Petrol.Модуль(7798)}: Ошибка при установке значения
>   атрибута контекста (ActiveConnection)    Command.ActiveConnection =
>   Connection; по причине: Произошла исключительная ситуация
>   (ADODB.Command): Для требуемой операции необходим объект OLE DB
>   Session, не поддерживаемый текущим поставщиком.

В чём может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Странно, что с драйвером от MySQL работало. У меня, в зависимости от версии MSSQL отрабатывали следующие строки:

DRIVER = {SQL Server}; SERVER = localhost; DataBase = *****; UID = user; PWD = ****

Provider=SQLOLEDB.1; User ID= user; Pwd=********; Data Source=localhost; Initial Catalog= *****

Попробуйте подобрать подходящую строку подключения на https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008/